# How to change Eclipse Console foreground color?

Tags: eclipse, appearance

Is there an option somewhere I can't find?

[image: dark blue doesn't look good at all on dark gray]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console (or a right click on the console window -> Preferences)

[image: Eclipse console settings]

Comment: There is no foreground color, just the background

Comment: Found it, it was in PyDev preferences.

Comment: @int_ua - "Standard Out text color" is the foreground color for regular text, "Standard Error text color" is the foreground color for error messages (Everything that is written to error stream using `System.err`);

Comment: @int_ua I think that PyDev is using a different console display, that's why these settings didn't work. See this link: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html